# Play Store: Will removing a credit card affect the google developer subscription?

Tags: android, google-play, credit-card

I just paid the `google play developer` subscription fee (25 USD) so i can publish apps on Google play store, now i want to remove the credit card i paid with, will this remove or affect the subscription ?

**Note** Google's answer was not quite clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Ts&Cs of a 3rd party service.

Comment: I see it as a very important question, It involves Google Play Store, and honestly go find something productive to do instead of writing comments like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google never gives simple answers.. You already paid for it so there should be no problem with removing credit card, but keep in mind that there you might not be able to sell your apps then.

Comment: I just want to add another credit card, because the card i paid the fee with was not mine.

Comment: when i click `remove` Google gives me this alert: `The following transactions will be affected by removing this credit card:
Google - Google Play`

Comment: I am not 100% sure but this will only make you unable to get a refund from that payment

Comment: Ok i'm gonna let them call me, there's an option for that, thanks anyway